# Multiline textbox set first line to bold font

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

i have a userform with a multiline textbox for the Adress in the format

Name1 Name2
Street Number
ZIP Place

Now i want to get the first line with the name to be bold. I have created a textbox in my UserForm which fills the textmark but i cant get it working that just the first line is bold and the rest just normal i just get it working that the whole textbox is bold.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rngDoc As Range
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim cText As String
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oBM As Bookmark

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

cText = TextBox5.Text

With oDoc
If .Bookmarks.Exists("Adresse") Then
Set oRng = .Bookmarks("Adresse").Range
oRng.Text = cText
Set oBM = .Bookmarks.Add(Name:="Adresse", Range:=oRng)
.Bookmarks("Adresse").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixxed my problem.

The first line in my text bookmark was already bold (marked it when i entered the text manually) thats why the code wasnt working and everything was getting bold. The code above is working and just making the first line bold which is entered in the text field !